# Convert Lazy<View> to Lazy<RelayCommand> and back

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to add description when attaching a file and I use MVVM Model. I create a commandHolder and from there create a command and I unable to convert a `Lazy<View>` to `Lazy<RelayCommand>` I request you to please help me in this.

```
this.fileAttachmentDescriptionCommandHolder = new Lazy<FileAttachmentDescriptionView>(() => new FileAttachmentDescriptionView { DataContext = this });

this.fileAttachmentDescriptionViewHolder = new Lazy<RelayCommand>(this.CreateFileAttachmentDescriptionCommand);
```

I get the error:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Lazy
>   Path.RelayCommand' to 'System.Lazy path.View'

Comment: Seems like you're assigning a view to a "commandHolder" and a command to a "viewHolder". This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks mechanic and Kevin

Comment: @SanthoshRajoo feel free to mark answer as an "Answer" by clickin the check mark below the voting buttons if it indeed answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing it backwards, as stated in the comment by mechanic.

```
this.fileAttachmentDescriptionCommandHolder = 
    new Lazy<RelayCommand>(this.CreateFileAttachmentDescriptionCommand);

this.fileAttachmentDescriptionViewHolder = 
    new Lazy<FileAttachmentDescriptionView>(
        () => new FileAttachmentDescriptionView { DataContext = this });
```